# Border Size change slow on resize()

Tags: jquery

I'm creating 2 triangles (using the border-*hack*), that fill the page vertically (so both triangles are 50% height of page). That I've done fine.

However, when I'm also trying to get this calc to run on `window.resize` it is very slow.
I'm aware I've got a few variables being calculated each time, but just wondering if anyone can think of a way to make this faster...
Have a look at my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrwigster/vuzs9/), and resize your browser window. - Warning the jsFiddle is likely to crash after a while.. that's how bad it is.

Currently the triangles work out the body width, minus the `.main` width, then divided by 2, so that the edges of the triangles just touch the side of `.main` div.
It also works out the height of the window (`$(window).outerHeight();`) then divides it by 2, so that each triangle has 50% of the window height.
It then also uses this height, to apply a `top` value to the 2nd triangle, so that it sits on the second half of page.

I suggest looking at the jsfiddle for the code, but will also put it here:

**HTML**

```
<div class="triangleWrap">
    <div class="borderTopLeft"></div>
    <div class="borderBottomLeft"></div>
</div>

<div class="main"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('document').ready(function triangleCalc() {
    var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
    var bodyHeight = $(window).outerHeight();
    var mainWidth = $('.main').width();
    var bodyMinusMain = (bodyWidth - mainWidth) / 2;
    var bodyHeightCalc = bodyHeight / 2;
    $('.borderTopLeft, .borderBottomLeft').css('border-right', bodyMinusMain + 'px solid black');
    $('.borderTopLeft').css('border-bottom', bodyHeightCalc + 'px solid transparent');
    $('.borderBottomLeft').css({
        'border-top': bodyHeightCalc + 'px solid transparent',
        'top': bodyHeightCalc + 'px'
    });
    $(window).resize(triangleCalc);
});​
```

**CSS**

```
.borderTopLeft, .borderBottomLeft{
    width: 0;    
    height: 0;    
    position: absolute;
}
.borderTopLeft{border-top: 0 solid transparent;}
.borderBottomLeft{border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;}
.borderTopLeft{ 
    border-bottom: 500px solid transparent;       
    border-right:438px solid #2C2C2C;
}
.borderBottomLeft{
    border-top: 500px solid transparent;   
    border-right: 600px solid #2C2C2C;
    top: 500px;
}
.main{width:500px;height:400px;background:orange;margin:auto;}
```

Comment: +1 from me.  Nice fiddle crash! ;-)  Seriously though, good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just badly written JavaScript. Not caching DOM references is the single worst thing to do.

Does that work better?: http://jsfiddle.net/NpDnu/

More optimizations:

- throttle the resize event (it's iconsistent across OSs/browsers anyway)
- decouple it and use requestAnimationFrame

Comment: its really makes change. nice job.. +1

Comment: Wow - much better thank you! - I guess I've mis-understood caching DOM references along the way. How does caching `body` to a body variable help, when the `width`, that we're after is a changing value anyway?

Comment: Because sizzle (http://sizzlejs.com/) needs to parse the string 'body', try to figure out what you want and then find the element in the document. That's costly. Despite all the stuff the jQuery function itself does, before it reaches sizzle.

Comment: Ah makes sense - I guess there's always functions behind the functions. OOP is a little crazy at times. Thanks again!